# Why I can't use weight paint for bones?

Tags: weight-painting, brushes

I want to change weight for the bones of my character, but it doesn't react on my actions. I've tried to disable paint mask mode, to pre-select all faces, but my character still doesn't react.

I only have automatic weights. As I found out, character's color should be brighter blue. I've tried to unparent the rig and parent it with empty groups but still no result. How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your brush settings:

[image]

Right now, you are using the *Add* brush with zero weights. Hence your brush effectively does nothing.

If you want your brush to "set" the weights to zero, change the Brush to *Draw*.
If you want to keep the Add brush, change the weight to anything more than zero to have an effect.

Comment: Oh my god... I've tried so many things, spend 5 days to know about drivers and other things that could be related to this... And it was so easy... Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to use the checkmark icon just below the votes to accept my answer for this topic.